# "This initial value does not corresponding to a stochastic node in WINBUGS

Tags: bayesian, random-effects, winbugs, proportions, meta-analysis

I have been trying this run this command to estimate two parameters pop.mean and tau.

```
model
{
 for( i in 1 : N ) 
  {
   r[i] ~ dbin(p[i], n[i]) #Model
   b[i] ~ dnorm(mu, prec.tau2)
   logit(p[i]) <- b[i]
  }
  mu ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-6) #Priors
  prec.tau2 ~dgamma(0.001,0.001)
  tau <- sqrt(1/prec.tau2)
  pop.mean <- exp(mu)/(1+exp(mu))
}
#Data
   list(n = c(47, 148, 119, 810, 211, 196, 148, 215, 207, 97, 256, 360),
   r = c(0, 18, 8, 46, 8, 13, 9, 31, 14, 8, 29, 24), N = 12)
  #Initial Values
   list(p = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
   mu = 0, prec.tau2 = 1)
```

However an error pops up stating "this initial value does not correspond to a stochastic node"
Can anyone help me with this solution.

I tried changing the initial values however I am unable to load the units and further proceed in estimating the two parameters.